# Airflow crashing when Job triggered

Tags: python, airflow, devops, python-3.7, airflow-scheduler

Getting Error:
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'XXXXXXXXXX' for key 'PRIMARY'")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1300, "Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '80047D'")
  result = self._query(query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 32, in 
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 236, in trigger_dag
    execution_date=args.exec_date)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/api/client/local_client.py", line 33, in trigger_dag
    execution_date=execution_date)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py", line 101, in trigger_dag
    replace_microseconds=replace_microseconds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py", line 77, in _trigger_dag
    external_trigger=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 4382, in create_dagrun
    run.refresh_from_db()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 5064, in refresh_from_db
    DR.run_id == self.run_id
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3332, in one
    raise orm_exc.NoResultFound("No row was found for one()")
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound: No row was found for one()

Airflow Version:1.10.2,SQLAlchemy:1.3.12 DB Engine: MYSQL

I tried many Solutions to fix this,but could not.
Can anyone help in fixing this issue.

Comment: You will need to provide the dag definition for us to determine what you are trying to do.

Comment: @saadi ,,Could you let me know why the dag definition is required ??Please note that Dag is running successful in python2.7.Its just am upgrading to python3.7 ,am getting this Error.

Comment: Oh right, well, I faced the same issue a few days ago, my version of python (`3.5.2`) wasn't compatible with airflow's latest version (`1.10`), which ran fine with python `3.6`. This implies that not every version of python is compatible with every version of airflow. I downgraded airflow one version and it worked fine with my version of python. So, I will suggest that you first confirm if the versions are compatible. You can also try destroying airflow database (IF YOU DON'T NEED META DATA OR HISTORY OF CURRENT DAGS) and then recreate it using `initdb`.

Comment: This is really frustrating that one version of airflow works with one version of python,and other works with different version of python.Let me see whether downgrading python will work.